# Field change event for ButtonField and BitmapField in Blackberry 4.6

Tags: blackberry

I am trying an app that has BitmapField and ButtonField too. When I click the BitmapField the field change event raise the BitmapField change and also ButtonField change event which is clicked before BitmapField in BlackBerrry 4.6.

Comment: I don't understand your second sentence about raising events.  Are you explaining your desired behavior, or the observed behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You should start with the RIM 4.6 [API documentation](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/index.html). Both ButtonField and BitmapField extend the Field class. That means that you can override methods from that class. The methods that might interest you are fieldChangeNotify and navigationClick.

```
ButtonField button = new ButtonField("Button1") {
   protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
      //code to handle click
   }
   protected void fieldChangeNotify(int context) {
      //code to handle field change(focus/unfocus/etc.)
   }
};
```